# For iterator with generic type - Java

Tags: java

I am having trouble with this piece of code. Basically, the main function was given, and it was asked to develop the most simple version of class `CountDown`, that compiles the code.

Class **Main**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CountDown a = new CountDown(3,15);
        CountDown b = new CountDown(2,20);
        CountDown c = new CountDown(3,15);

        List<CountDown> lst = new ArrayList<CountDown>();
        lst.add(a);
        lst.add(b);
        lst.add(c);

        Set<CountDown> set = new HashSet<CountDown>();
        set.addAll(lst);

        lst.clear();
        lst.addAll(set);
        Collections.sort(lst);

        for(E e : lst) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Class **CountDown**:

```
public class CountDown implements Comparable<CountDown> {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    public CountDown(int hour, int minute) throws Exception {

        if ((hour > 23 || hour < 0) && (minute > 59 || minute < 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Horas ou minutos invalidos");
        } else {
            this.hour = hour;
            this.minute = minute;
        }
    }

    public int gethour() {
        return this.hour;
    }

    public int getminute() {
        return this.minute;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CountDown arg0) {
        int result = 0;
        int minute1 = arg0.getminute();
        int hour1 = arg0.gethour();

        result = this.getminute() - minute1;

        if(result == 0) {
            result = this.gethour() - hour1;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

My problem is that in Main function this piece of code doesn't compile, and I have no idea on how to make it work. Can someone teach me whats wrong?

```
for(E e : lst) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Add a `toString()` method to your class.

Comment: Also, you say "_this piece of code doesn't compile_" - in that case show us the exact error you get.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type 
  CountDown to E
 - E cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this to work properly, you probably need a few things.

First up, you will need a trivial interface or class `E`:

```
public interface E
{

}
```

The add the following bits to `CountDown`.  Note comments where things have changed:

```
// Added "implements E" and provided trivial interface E
// to allow (for E : ...) to work in main(...).
public class CountDown implements E, Comparable<CountDown> {
  private int hour;
  private int minute;

  // Removed unnecessary "throws Exception" specifier
  public CountDown(int hour, int minute) {
    // Previous logic incorrect.  Should throw exception if either hour
    // OR minute is out of range.
    if (hour > 23 || hour < 0 || minute > 59 || minute < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Horas ou minutos invalidos");
    } else {
      this.hour = hour;
      this.minute = minute;
    }
  }

  // Corrected capitalisation to make bean compliant name.
  // Not strictly required.
  public int getHour() {
    return this.hour;
  }

  // Corrected capitalisation to make bean compliant name.
  // Not strictly required.
  public int getMinute() {
    return this.minute;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(CountDown other) {
    // Simplified logic.  Made sort by hours, then by minutes.
    int cmp = Integer.compare(this.getHour(), other.getHour());
    if (cmp == 0)
      cmp = Integer.compare(this.getMinute(), other.getMinute());
    return cmp;
  }

  // Really should have equals(...) method if instances are comparable.
  // Also required if we want to use instances in a HashSet
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o)
  {
    if (this == o)
      return true;
    if (o instanceof CountDown)
    {
      CountDown other = (CountDown)o;
      // Ensures that this logic is consistent with compareTo(...)
      return this.compareTo(other) == 0;
    }
    return false;
  }

  // Really should have hashCode() if we have equals.
  // Also required if we want to use instances in a HashSet
  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    // Collision-free hash code given logic in constructor.
    return this.hour * 60 + this.minute;
  }

  // Required to show a sensible value for System.out.print(...) etc
  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("%s[%02d:%02d]", getClass().getSimpleName(),
        this.getHour(), this.getMinute());
  }
}
```

Given these changes, `main(...)` should run without modifications.

Comment: Could you, if possible, explain the idea behind hashcode? I am not really understanding

Comment: `hashCode()` is used for "bucketing" for data structures that use this approach.  There is a wikipedia page (!) here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode() and JavaDoc for `Object.hashCode()` here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--

Comment: `for(E e : lst)` in `main` has to be an error in the specification.  There is no reason to introduce a useless empty interface, and calling it `E` probably reflects that class `Main` was generic at some point.

Comment: @JimGarrison, that seems likely, unless it is intended as a puzzle for folks to solve.

Comment: It was definitely a puzzle. The main function was exactly as I wrote. But thanks for the help guys. I am enjoying this community. Hope to get more knowledge and then answer some questions too ;)

Answer (score 5):

Your `lst` variable is a list of `CountDown` objects, so if you change `E` to `CountDown` here:

```
for(E e : lst) {
```

it should work.

Comment: But the question asks to dont change in Main function

Comment: @PedroMartins, I think you were given a main function with a mistake in it. I don't see another way to do it.

Comment: Probably... The only thing that was given was the main function, and it says
1) please make the simplest version of countdown that compiles the code

Comment: @PabloCanseco, thanks pablo, thats what I was thinking

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to make your countdown class implement a `E` interface. That was a tricky assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you'll need to do to remove the compilation errors:

1. `lst` contains elements of type `CountDown` therefore the enhanced for loop variable should be of type `CountDown` not `E` i.e. `for(CountDown e : lst) { ... }`.
2. Since there is a chance that your constructor could throw an exception you'll either need to declare main as `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {` or wrap the code inside a `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the values of the CountDown class,Please override tostring() method as well.. hope it will work...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class Test{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                List<CountDown> lst = new ArrayList<CountDown>();
                CountDown a = new CountDown(3,15);
                CountDown b = new CountDown(2,20);
                CountDown c = new CountDown(3,15);
                lst.add(a);
                lst.add(b);
                lst.add(c);
                Set<CountDown> set = new HashSet<CountDown>();
                set.addAll(lst);
                lst.clear();
                lst.addAll(set);
                Collections.sort(lst);
                for(CountDown e : lst) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

        }

    }
     class CountDown implements Comparable<CountDown>{
        private int hour;
        private int minute;

        public CountDown(int hour, int minute) throws Exception {
            if ((hour > 23 || hour < 0) && (minute > 59 || minute < 0)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Horas ou minutos invalidos");
            } else {
                this.hour = hour;
                this.minute = minute;
            }
        }

        public int gethour() {
            return this.hour;
        }

        public int getminute() {
            return this.minute;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(CountDown arg0) {
            int result = 0;
            int minute1 = arg0.getminute();
            int hour1 = arg0.gethour();
            result = this.getminute() - minute1;
            if(result == 0) {
                result = this.gethour() - hour1;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It has two errors.
1. CountDown class constructor is marked as "throws exception". When you create an instance of it, it needs to be wrapped it into Try-Catch block.
2. When you iterate the collection of CountDown list, the specified type was wrong in for loop.
3. Fix System.out.println to print user-friendly info.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CountDown> lst = new ArrayList<CountDown>();
        try
        {
            CountDown a = new CountDown(3,15);
            CountDown b = new CountDown(2,20);
            CountDown c = new CountDown(3,15);
            lst.add(a);
            lst.add(b);
            lst.add(c);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        Set<CountDown> set = new HashSet<CountDown>();
        set.addAll(lst);
        lst.clear();
        lst.addAll(set);
        Collections.sort(lst);
        for(CountDown e : lst) {
            System.out.println("Hours: " + e.gethour() + " Minutes: " + e.getminute());
        }

    }
}
```